# Scala-meta for instrumentation

Tags: scala, scalameta

I noticed that scala-meta provides transformation functions, but not functions to insert additional code (e.g., import statements, or a method call at every start of a function).

Since all structures (scala.meta.Tree and its children) are immutable, I'm not sure if it possible and how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, A new tree structure has to be built based on the original with whatever modifications are desired.  [Tree.transform](http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#Tree.transform) allows just such a thing.